# How to list files in /data/anr in Android 6.0?

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-anr-dialog

I want to get the files in /data/anr in Java Code.

```
String path = "/data/anr";
File traceDir = new File(path);
if(traceDir != null && traceDir.isDirectory()){
   File[] files1 = traceDir.listFiles();
}
```

in Android 5.0 and below , the method `isDirectory()` returns true and I can use `listFiles()` to get the files in /data/anr , but in Android 6.0 and above , it doesn't work. `IsDirectory()` returns false and `listFiles()` returns null. Anybody can help me for it? Many thx.

Comment: Request run-time permission for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: @tahsinRupam I have tried it , but it still didn't work for me. I changed the directory to "data/data" , and invoked the isDirectory method , it returns true.